# Android TalkBack reading phone numbers in Webview incorrectly

Tags: android, webview, accessibility, talkback

I'm having a minor headache with the TalkBack screen reader service when reading phone numbers in a WebView, and I can't seem to find a solution.  This is a snippet of some html code that I am reading into the WebView:

```
<li>Call <a href="tel:18007848669">1-800-QUIT-NOW(1-800-784-8669)</a> for phone support</li>
```

The screen reader reads this as "Call one to eight hundred quit now one to eight hundred link".  Is there a way to force it/signal to read it differently?  I need it to be read in a more natural format, i.e. "One Eight Hundred".

Comment: What do you want it to say?

Comment: I just need it to stop saying "One to Eight Hundred", and to use a more natural phone number format "One Eight Hundred".  I updated the post.

Comment: Not possible to my knowledgeq

Comment: Awesome, thanks :).  That's always the client's favorite answer :).

Comment: This is a bug in the text-to-speech engine. Should be fixed in newer versions of Android.

Comment: That's interesting...I'm testing on a N10 with the newest version of Jellybean that's been pushed to the device.  Regardless, glad to know it's an OS bug and not a specific bug to our app.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this element,
    android:contentDescription="One eight hundred quit now"

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Accessibility Deligate for your editText or textView

```
@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

        switch (host.getId()) {
            case R.id.tv_bookingID:
                if (((TextView) host).getText().length() > 1) {
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                    for (char c : ((TextView) host).getText().toString().toCharArray()) {
                        sb.append(c).append(" ");
                    }
                    //change text for talkback
                    info.setText(null);
                    info.setContentDescription(sb.toString().trim());

                }
                break;
        }//switch
    }//if
}
```