# Android accessibility announcement reads textview differently than what I expected

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

For example, after setting Text in `TextView` to '347309', `TalkBack` should read "three, four, seven, three, zero(or o), nine."
But it announced "three hundred forty- seven thousand thirty nine."

In another case,
I set text 'API' (Application Programming Interface).
I want TalkBack to announce "A-P-I," but it announces "eipi" or "eipaɪ."

How do I get `TalkBack` to announce correctly?

Comment: This *may* help (basically stripping out the characters in the contentDescription and replaying them back). Haven't tried it myself though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371057/android-talkback-reading-phone-numbers-in-webview-incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Click here to check code. You need to take char array of that string and make separate each char with appending space and set that string as a content description to your view.

Here's the code :

```
Var str="347309"
textView.setContentDescription =getCharFromText(str)
fun getCharFromText(str:String):String
{
  Var sb= StringBuilder()
  foreach(c in str.charArray())
  {    
    sb.append("")
    sb.append(c).append(" ")
  }
  return sb.tostring()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Talkback has built-in functionality to adjust how text is read. By swiping up or down the screen, the user is able to go from default to reading out the text letter-by-letter if they need to.

It's preferable to allow the user to control this via existing controls, rather than force this choice programmatically.